# php how to detect if a round() has been rounded

Tags: php, rounding

Let's say I have variables like this:

```
$X = 5;
$Y = 12.6784543287;
```

If I use round() I get something like this

```
round($X,0) // 5
round($Y,0) // 13
```

How to create a condition that detect if a round has truncated in order to adapt the sign "="/"≈" ?

```
echo 'x'.round($X,0) // x = 5
echo 'y'.round($Y,0) // y ≈ 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example do :

```
function printTruncated($val)
{
    if($val == round($val, 0))
        return ' = ' . round($val, 0);
    else
        return ' ≈ ' . round($val, 0);
}

echo 'x' . printTruncated($X) // x = 5
echo 'y' . printTruncated($Y) // y ≈ 13
```

Comment: that's so simple =D

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to save the rounded values in two additional variables and output the sign like this:

```
<?= $yRounded === $Y ? '=' : '≈' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**My answer :D**

```
<?php
$X = $X1 = 5;
$Y = $Y1 = 12.6784543287;
echo ( $X == (round($X1,0)) ) ? 'X='.$X : 'X≈'.$X;
echo ( $Y == round($Y1,0) ) ? 'Y='.$Y : 'Y≈'.$Y;
```

Comment: that works.. a bit complicated but that was an occasion to learn a bit =)